# Loop for over the condition

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiple(int, int);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("%d", multiple(x,y));
} 

int multiple(int N,int M)
{
    int i;
    int result;
    for (i=0;i*M<N;i++) 
    {
        result=i*M;
        printf("%d", result);
    }
}
```

When I put input (for example x=100 and y=7) the output displays all the multiple until 105 and not until 98 as it should be.

Comment: Both `main` and `multiple` return `int` but you're not returning any value. Make sure you pay attention to compiler warnings. If you're using GCC, always use at least `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: PS i made a mistake also declaring int  i and not using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop does print up to 98. However, `multiple` is declared to return an `int` but doesn't actually have a `return` statement, so the return value is unspecified (and in practice you'll get some arbitrary value from a previous calculation). Then you print this "garbage" return value and in your case it happens to be 105.

If you don't want `multiple` to return a value then don't declare it to return a value, and don't print the value it returns.

Comment: Maybe it could be a stupid question but how i print a "garbage" return?

Comment: @FulvioDenza `printf("%d", multiple(x,y));` prints the return value of `multiple(x,y)`. Here "garbage" just means data that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Thank you very much @immibis